# Is it possible to extract emails from an email list

Tags: list, email

So my university has an email list in the form of:

```
students@lists.university.edu
```

If I send an email to `students@lists.university.edu` it will send the email to all people in the list. My question is, how do I extract the emails individually giving me:

```
email1@university.edu
email2@university.edu
email3@university.edu
email4@university.edu
email5@university.edu
email6@university.edu
email7@university.edu
```

Comment: Is there a way to get access to this this list directly?

Comment: I think you'd have to have admin access to the mailing-list server to get that information.  Note that many people on the mailing list might consider it a violation of their privacy if their email addresses are being accessed by people other than that mailing-list administrators.

Comment: @SamOwl I have been looking but can't find the full list.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner it is a list open for students to use freely to email everyone else. Often used to send out a request for people to take a survey, etc.

Comment: Being able to send an email to a mailing list is not the same thing as collecting the recipients' email addresses -- with the former, one can emails to the people on the mailing list, but only as long as they remain subscribed to the list; with the latter, someone could sell the email addresses to spammers, and then the recipients end up receiving spam for as long as they have that email account.  That's one reason why many mailing list packages try to keep recipients' email-addresses private rather than just putting everybody's email address on the cc: line.